# JDBC: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java

I was trying to read records from MySQL database and put it in a class variable in JDBC but it throws exception `The Error is: java.lang. NullPointerException`.

What is it that I am doing wrong here?

### Code:

```
 try {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/databasename", "root", "password");
        st = conn.createStatement();
        rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM tablename");
        kids records = new kids();
        int i = 0;
        while (rs.next()) {
            records.id[i] = rs.getInt("id");
            records.name[i] = rs.getString("name");
            records.user_id[i] = rs.getInt("user_id");
            System.out.println("id: " + records.id[i] + "name: " + records.name[i] + "user_id" + records.user_id[i]);
            i++;
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("The Error: " + e);
    }
```

The kid class, which is supposed to store the records is as follows.

```
  public class kids{
    public int id[];
    public String name[];
    public int user_id[];
    public kids(){
        for (int x=0;x<100;x++){
         this.id[x]=0;
         this.name[x]="";
         this.user_id[x]=0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what Exception are you getting  ?

Comment: please share the stack trace

Comment: Post the stack trace, find the line number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the arrays inside your `kids` class are `null` since that's the default value for objects (an array is an object). You should initialize them in the class constructor:

```
private static final int MAX_ARRAY = 100;
public kids(){
    this.id = new int[MAX_ARRAY];
    this.name = new String[MAX_ARRAY];
    this.user_id= new int[MAX_ARRAY];
    for (int x=0; x<MAX_ARRAY; x++){
        this.id[x]=0;
        this.name[x]="";
        this.user_id[x]=0;
    }
}
```

---

There are other several problems with your current design that you should work on:

- Use the [Java Code Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf), so rename your class `kids` to `Kid`, your variable `kids records` to `Kid kid`, and on...
- A class should store the data for an entity, your `kid` class is currently storing parallel arrays for data. It would be better to have a `Kid` class with `int id; String name; int user_id;` fields and `KidHolder` class which contains a `Kid[] kidHolder` instead.
- Arrays have a static size and cannot be changed, so if you don't know how many elements will retrieve and hold (e.g. when retrieving data from database), use a `List` instead.
- **Do not** open database connections manually, instead use a database connection pool that will enhance the database access by opening lot of connections and keeping them sleep, because opening a database connection has a **high** cost.

Taking into account all these advices, your design should be like this:

```
public class Kid {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int userId;
    //getters and setters
}

public class KidHolder {
    private List<Kid> kidHolder;
    public KidHolder() {
        kidHolder = new ArrayList<Kid>();
    }
    public void add(Kid kid) {
    }
}

//...

List<Kid> kidList = new ArrayList<Kid>();
try {
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/databasename", "root", "password");
    st = conn.createStatement();
    rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM tablename");
    //kids records = new kids();
    //int i = 0;
    while (rs.next()) {
        Kid kid = new Kid();
        //records.id[i] = rs.getInt("id");
        //records.name[i] = rs.getString("name");
        //records.user_id[i] = rs.getInt("user_id");
        kid.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
        kid.setName(rs.getInt("name"));
        kid.setUserId(rs.getInt("user_id"));
        System.out.println("id: " + kid.getId() + "name: " + kid.getName() + "user_id" + kid.getUserId());
        kidList.add(kid);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println("The Error: " + e);
} finally {
    closeResource(rs);
    closeResource(st);
    closeResource(conn);
}
//probably you should return kidList to display it in your view

//method to close the connection
//create two more similar methods to close ResultSet and Statement...
public void closeResource(Connection con) {
    if (con != null) {
        try {
            con.close();
        } catch (SQLException silent) {
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the time you take to specify what needs to be work on there. Its been ages since I use Java, so I really needed your help. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

You have not instantiated any of the members,

```
public int id[];
public String name[];
public int user_id[];
```

Even the constructor would fail at `this.id[x]=0;`